# Can I use a public Domain Name (DNS Server) to connect to a Hyper-V VM running a Mastondon instance

Tags: hyper-v, windows-11, mastodon

I've read through most of the Hyper-V / DNS entries and they seem to mostly be about finding domain name inside the VM or from the Windows host.

Mine is the opposite, I'd like to kick the tires on running a Maston instance in an Ubuntu VM under Hyper-V. So I'd like it to federate with other instances running on the public internet.

I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work, have I missed something?

I have a decent tower PC with Intel Core i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz + 64GB RAM. I'm doing a few other minor Windows tests using VM's already but none of them run in Hyper-V for more than an hour at a time. So the system should be fast enough.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe this would be more appropriate to ask on https://serverfault.com/ as the question is not programming related